Angular 17 update "Unable to resolve @nx/workspace:run-commands"
Currently i updated my project to Angular 17 with nx and when i try to build my application, i get the error which wasnt happening before :
Cannot find executor 'run-commands' in C:\Users\tamart\Desktop\build-UI\ui-build\node_modules\@nx\workspace\executors.json.

what could be the problem ? thanks !
     "executor": "@nx/workspace:run-commands",
                "options": {
                  "commands": [
                    "nx run node-gateway-autologin:build-main",
                    "ts-node-script ./build/bundle-lib.ts bundle libs/node-gateway-autologin dist/libs/node-gateway-autologin"
                  ],
                  "parallel": false
                },
                "configurations": {}

Here is the package.json. All libraries are updated.
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "17.1.4",
    "@angular/animations": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "17.1.3",
    "antlr4": "^4.9.3",
    "debug": "^4.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.14.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "17.1.3",
    "@nrwl/tao": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/angular": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/eslint": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/jest": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/node": "17.3.2",
    "@nx/workspace": "17.3.2",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.4.13",
    "@types/superagent": "^4.1.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.13.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.13.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "commander": "^8.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "jest": "29.4.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "~28.1.1",
    "ng-packagr": "17.1.2",
    "ng-swagger-gen": "^2.3.1",
    "nx": "17.3.2",
    "nx-remotecache-custom": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  }


Did you migrate nx too? https://nx.dev/features/automate-updating-dependencies. Probably the executor you need now is nx:run-commands, but let the nx migrate tool do it for you.  nx migrate nx@version

Can you provide more details about the versions of Nx and Angular you're using? Also, could you share your package.json and the configuration files where the executor is defined? This will help in understanding the context of the issue better.

@OscarLudick i did but no luck :/

@Verity i updated the question. Executors are being used in project-graph.json.

Your package.json looks good, could you try and reinstall the packages by deleting your node_modules folder and running npm install? You may also want to check afterwards if the execuor exists in node_modules\@nx\workspace\executors.json. If it's missing you may want to check if Nx has relocated or removed the executor in the newer version and/or check their documentation for a migration guide.
